# Selected value for DropDownListFor not being set in model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdownlistfor

I have been searching for many hours and tried all the suggestion. I assume I am missing some basic concept. I want to use model not `ViewBag`, and I have the selected item/value be set in the model on the post back.

I am setting up a ddl and action link in cshtml as follows:

```
@model VinExampleProject.Models.MembersModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.SearchColumn, new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem {Text = "Select A Column", Value = "1" },
    new SelectListItem {Text = "UserName", Value = "2" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "FirstName", Value = "3" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "LastName", Value = "4" }
}
            , "Select A Column")

@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Search", Model)
```

The controller has this method

```
public ActionResult Search(MembersModel mModel)
{
    // mModel.SearchColumn always 0 or empty string (i have tried both types in the model)
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I expect `mModel.SearchColumn` to be set to the select item/value, but is always empty.

This is my model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class MembersModel 
{
    // public enum SearchColumns { UserName, FirstName, LastName };

    ///<summary>
    /// Gets or sets Customers.
    ///</summary>
    public List<Member> Members { get; set; }

    ///<summary>
    /// Gets or sets CurrentPageIndex.
    ///</summary>
    public int CurrentPageIndex { get; set; }

    ///<summary>
    /// Gets or sets PageCount.
    ///</summary>
    public int MembersPerPage { get; set; }

    ///<summary>
    /// Gets or sets column to sort by.
    ///</summary>
    public string SortColumn { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Total amount of actib=ve mambers
    /// </summary>
    public int ActiveMemberCount { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Column to search
    /// </summary>
    public int SearchColumn { get; set; }  // also have tried string here

    /// <summary>
    /// Value to search for
    /// </summary>
    public string SearchValue { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that not only the `SearchColumn` is empty, but also all the other properties of your model are empty when you reach the `Search` action. To get the values sent from the form to your action, you need to put them in a form and submit the form.

```
@model VinExampleProject.Models.MembersModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Search", FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SearchColumn, Model.SearchColumnList, "Select A Column")
    <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" />
}
```

Notice that I've also added the `AntiForgeryToken` for you, which is recommended to protect your website. I also recommend moving your items list to your model:

```
public class MembersModel {
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SearchColumnList { get; set; }
}
```

And your action must have the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` and the `HttpPost` attributes. You will generate the list items as part of the model in the `HttpGet` action:

```
public ActionResult Search() {
    var model = new MembersModel();
    model.SearchColumnList = new List<SelectListItem> {
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Select A Column", Value = "1" },
        new SelectListItem {Text = "UserName", Value = "2" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "FirstName", Value = "3" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "LastName", Value = "4" }
    }
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Search(MembersModel model)
{
    //Now your model will be populated with the values from the form
}
```

If you really want to use a link, then you should consider using Ajax. You can serialize your form fields in JavaScript using the jQuery `serialize()` function and then send them via Ajax. Something like this:

```
<a id="SearchLink" href="#">Search</a>
<script>
    $('#SearchLink).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
        $.post("@Url.Action("Search", "Search"), $("#myForm").serialize(), function(data) {
            alert("Data sent successfully!");
        });
      return false;
    });
</script>
```

Alternatively (and probably a better approach you), can make the form itself an Ajax form and so it will submit itself via Ajax and call a JavaScript callback function when it's done:

```
@model VinExampleProject.Models.MembersModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Search", null, new AjaxOptions {
             OnSuccess = "SearchSuccessCallback(data);",
             OnFailure = "SearchFailureCallback();"
        })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SearchColumn, Model.SearchColumnList, "Select A Column")
    <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" />
}
<script>
    function SearchSuccessCallback(data) {
        alert("Data sent successfully!");
    }
    function SearchFailureCallback() {
        alert("There was an error!");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I am trying this but the @using is being flagged as an error.  the name using does not exist int the current context

Comment: That's a bizarre error. I missed one bracket, check my updated answer.

Comment: I am trying this but am getting run time error There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SearchColumn'.

Comment: OK,  this is (sort of) working now. I get a model with the selected value but only the selected value.  All other model values are null or 0.  But i can work with that.  thank you for you prompt response.

Comment: Of course the rest will be empty, because I only included the `SearchColumn` in the form. Add all the other fields and everything will work.